# DropDown is not working in mvc view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i don,t know why but the dropdown is my mvc view is not working, is use all bootstrap files but still its not working

```
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle user-state:active" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Guide <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown open">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Diamond <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 1 })">Carat Weight</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 2 })">Clarity</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Emerald <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 3 })">Clarity</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 4 })">Color</a></li>
                    <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 5 })">Cut</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create a menu and your code looks fine. I just tried to create a menu and placed the code under a menu list as below and it is working fine. Hope this helps.

```
<style>    
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
        left: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        margin-top: -1px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
        visibility: visible;
    }


    .navbar .sub-menu:before {
        border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        border-top: 7px solid transparent;
        left: -7px;
        top: 10px;
    }

    .navbar .sub-menu:after {
        border-top: 6px solid transparent;
        border-left: none;
        border-right: 6px solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
        left: 10px;
        top: 11px;
        left: -6px;
    }

</style>

<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle user-state:active" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Guide <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Diamond <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 1 })">Carat Weight</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 2 })">Clarity</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Emerald <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 3 })">Clarity</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 4 })">Color</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("GuideView" , "Base" , new { id = 5 })">Cut</a></li>
             </ul>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </li>
```

Comment: there is no difference in our code but my code not showing inner dropdown

Comment: I have edited the code to display the inner dropdown. Could you please try this.

Answer (score 0):

This will work and will look like proper bootstrap.

```
   <style>
 .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }

        .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
            top: 0;
            left: 100%;
            margin-top: -6px;
            margin-left: -1px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
            -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
            border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
            display: block;
            content: " ";
            float: right;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-color: transparent;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
            border-left-color: #ccc;
            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-right: -10px;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
            border-left-color: #fff;
        }

        .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
            float: none;
        }

            .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
                left: -100%;
                margin-left: 10px;
                -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
                -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
                border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
            }
    </style 



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                Guide
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Diamond</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Carat Weight</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Clarity</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>              
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a href="#" tabindex="-1">Emerald</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Clarity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Color</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cut</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working, just showing normal list, i want dropdown

Comment: It is a dropdown, you must add the style aswell. The result of the code I gave you is when you click it dropsdown with "Diamond" and "Emerald" wirh the extra dropdown added to the twe options.@RajatZade